# PHP - echo before exec()

Tags: php, exec, echo

Good day!

I am having some issues with getting the echo statement to output before the execution of the exec()

```
 <?
    if (isset($_POST['ipaddress'])) {
       $escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($_POST['ipaddress']);

       if(filter_var($escaped_command, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
           echo "Gleaning ARP information, please wait..";
           $command = exec('sudo /sbin/getarp.exp');
```

The echo statement is being outputted after the execution of the $command. The execution time can be anywhere from 15-30 seconds depending on how large the ARP table on the remote router is. Is there an order of operations that I am not aware of? It appears that all the statements within the if statement are executed in parallel and not by line by line as I had assumed.

I would rather not a solution be provided, but some documentational links that would lead me to finding a solution. I have searched what I could, but was not able to find a viable solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP there is a concept of "output buffering".

Whenever you output something (e.g. using `echo`, `print`, etc.) the text is thrown into a buffer. This buffer is only sent at certain times (at the end of the request, for instance, or when the buffer is full).

In order to empty the buffer (to "flush" it) you need to do it manually. The [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush) function will do this. Sometimes you also need to call [`ob_flush()`](http://php.net/ob_flush) (this is if you have opened custom output buffers yourself). It is generally a good idea to just call both functions and be done with it:

```
echo 'Wait a few seconds...';
flush(); ob_flush();
sleep(3);
echo ' aaand we are done!';
```

See [Output Buffering Control](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) for more information on output buffering in PHP.

Comment: The Output Buffering Control link is what I needed to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the script will run in its entirety before any result/output is sent to the browser.

Comment: As a follow up, you can consider using Javascript to write your message before the request to your PHP-script is done.

Comment: I've had php files before that will print right when you call echo, but I'm not sure how. I think certain headers were sent?

Comment: @DamienBlack How long did it take the entire script to execute?

Comment: Several minutes, and it would update as I echoed... This was in a framework, but there wasn't any javascript.

Comment: "This is happening because the script will run in its entirety before any result/output is sent to the browser."

I don't think this is true.

Comment: @immersiontravis In the vast majority of cases, it is.

Comment: Ah, I found it. ob_implicit_flush (true) is called at the top.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with the output buffer. PHP buffers output and writes it to the browser in chunks. Try adding a call to [ob_flush()](https://www.php.net/ob_flush) between the echo and the exec(); this will force PHP to write the current contents of the buffer to the browser.

Comment: Probably better to run an Ajax request.

Comment: Good point. Otherwise, the user will be sitting there with a half-downloaded page while the exec() statement runs.

Comment: Yep. And you're going to have cross-browser issues with flushing (unfortunately).

Comment: Just curious: do you have any links that explain this? I've not heard this before. Of course, I rarely use ob_flush() anyway, but it'd be nice to know...

Comment: The last time I was messing around with flushing, I saw people arguing over what browser (and what version) would do what (not to mention arguments about certain PHP/server setups). It was enough to make me back away from it and use Ajax instead.

Answer (score 0):

By default, php does not send any of the output until the php script is done running completely. There is a solution. However, I hear it is a little browser dependent. I would test it on different systems and browsers to see if it is working:

```
ob_implicit_flush (true)
```

Put that before any of your echo/print commands and that should allow anything printed to show right up on the browser.

A more universal approach would be to integrate your page with asynchronous javascript. A process commonly referred to as "AJAX". It is a little more difficult because it requires the use of many interacting scripts, some client-side and some server-side. However, AJAX is the defacto way to do thing like this on the web.